# How can I get early access to upcoming Asp.Net Identity changes?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

Since there are a lot of changes between each version of Asp.Net Identity, is there a way to get early access to any upcoming changes going forward?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We've started publishing nightly builds to the [aspnetwebstacknightly myget feed](http://www.myget.org/f/aspnetwebstacknightly/).  Currently the 1.0.0 RTM candidate version is already on the feed.  Going forward as we start working on future releases, this feed will contain those previews as well.

**Update:** [Walkthrough post on how to get access](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/09/asp-net-identity-nuget-packages-for-the-nightly-builds-are-available-on-myget.aspx)

Comment: Do you publish the source code also somewhere? I have looked at: http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest but could not find any AspNet.Identity files. Having access to the source would make it a lot easier to figure out what is going on.

Comment: Its not open source yet, until that happens, we can't publish source code

Comment: I've registered with www.myget.org but it still requires credentials to access this feed.

Comment: Please read the following post about this availability http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/09/asp-net-identity-nuget-packages-for-the-nightly-builds-are-available-on-myget.aspx