# How do you create a user with Asp.Net RTM bits using AspNet.Identity?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

How do you create a user with Asp.Net RTM bits using AspNet.Identity?

I moved to the AspNet Identity RTM bits that @Hao Kung posted about here: [How can I get early access to upcoming Asp.Net Identity changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18793746/how-can-i-get-early-access-to-upcoming-asp-net-identity-changes)

The RC Asp.Net identity code for registering a user looks like this...

```
protected void CreateUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string userName = UserName.Text;
    var manager = new AuthenticationIdentityManager(new IdentityStore());
    User u = new User(userName) { UserName = userName };
    IdentityResult result = manager.Users.CreateLocalUser(u, Password.Text);
    if (result.Success) 
    {
        manager.Authentication.SignIn(Context.GetOwinContext().Authentication, u.Id, isPersistent: false);
        OpenAuthProviders.RedirectToReturnUrl(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"], Response);
    }
    else 
    {
        ErrorMessage.Text = result.Errors.FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

My question is similar to that found here...
[How do you login/authenticate a user with Asp.Net MVC5 RTM bits using AspNet.Identity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19091157/how-do-you-login-authenticate-a-user-with-asp-net-mvc5-rtm-bits-using-aspnet-ide)

But I am asking about creating a user, not the sign-in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what the Register method looks like, its basically creating a user with a password:

```
    //
    // POST: /Account/Register
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model) {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) {
            var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.UserName };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded) {
                await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else {
                AddErrors(result);
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best way or whether or not this will change before RTM is offical but this seems to do the trick...

```
    protected void CreateUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string userName = UserName.Text;
        var manager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext();
        ApplicationUser u = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = userName };
        var userMangager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>());

        IdentityResult result = userMangager.Create(u, Password.Text);
        if (result.Succeeded) 
        {
            manager.Authentication.SignIn();
            OpenAuthProviders.RedirectToReturnUrl(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"], Response);
        }
        else 
        {
            ErrorMessage.Text = result.Errors.FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
```